# How to add a new column rank on based on increasing value of other column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have this dataframe with which i am trying to create a new column **rank** on basis of increasing values of column **Opportunity** with pandas

```
State   Brand       DYA     Opportunity
Delhi   Pampers     -8.58   -1.24139
Delhi   Ariel       0.53    0.04800
Delhi   Fusion      0.68    0.00492
Delhi   Gillette    1.56    0.02073
```

required output --

```
State   Brand       DYA     Opportunity Rank
Delhi   Pampers     -8.58   -1.24139     1
Delhi   Ariel       0.53    0.04800      4      
Delhi   Fusion      0.68    0.00492      2
Delhi   Gillette    1.56    0.02073      3
```

Comment: why the rank of 0.00492 is 4? I think it should be 2.

Comment: @Phoenix my bad!! can you help me further on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `rank` function:

```
df['Rank'] = df['Opportunity'].rank()
```

[image]